# Selecting the last element after split in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to select the last string after splitting it in Azure Data Factory.

My file name looks like this:

`s = "cloudboxacademy/covid19/main/ecdc_data/hospital_admissions.csv"`

With Python I would use `s.split('/')[-1]` to get the last element, according to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#last) I can use `last` to achieve this, so I've tried this in the sink database Pipeline expression builder:

`@last(split(dataset().fileName, '/'))`

Which gives me a red underline stating:

> Cannot fit string list item into the function parameter string

However, after running the pipeline I get what I desire, the file named `hospital_admissions.csv` placed in the folder I want it to go, so my question is if I am chaining the functions correctly & why am I having the error with a working code?

Answer (score 5):

The pipeline expression builder might be recognizing the value generated by `split(dataset().fileName,'/')` as an array. Hence the message **Cannot fit string list item into the function parameter string**.

[image]

- However, while executing, it is giving the expected output.
- To make it so that the warning `Cannot fit string list item into the function parameter string` is not shown, you can use the result of `split` along with `array` function. You can still chain the function using the following dynamic content and get expected result:

```
@last(array(split(dataset().filename,'/')))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can do the following:
Create 2 Variables:
Variable 1 (Array):

```
@split('cloudboxacademy/covid19/main/ecdc_data/hospital_admissions.csv', '/')
```

Variable 2 (String):

```
@last(variables('test'))
```

[image: OutputVariable1]

[image: OutputVariable2]

[image: VariableDeclaration]

Comment: That seems unnecessary for such a simple task, I would prefer to do it in one line than having to create one time variables. My question is the chaining of operations in ADF.

Comment: I agree that creating additional variable is dirty and it should be omitted if it can be done.   
@saideep-arikontham has provided a cleaner and simpler solution.